# Inserting data into list of map taking too much time in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, documentum, documentum-dfc

I have a task to send the automated report daily. So, I'm basically writing the query result set/collection into list of map so that I can write that data to excel. Here, I have the following method that inserts collection data into list of map. The problem is this method takes 1 hour 20 minutes to insert data from the collection which has 3000-3500 rows and 14 columns. In my code I have 5 similar queries to run and for each query it is taking same amount of time. Can you please help me in optimizing the code so that it takes less amount of time?

```
// avoided following method

public static List<Map<String, Object>> insertAttrValues(IDfCollection dfCollection, List<String> attributes) throws DfException {

    if (dfCollection == null || attributes == null) {
        throw new MissingParameterException("collection and attributes");
    }

    List<Map<String, Object>> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

    while (dfCollection.next()) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(attributes.size());

        for (String attribute: attributes) {
            map.put(attribute, dfCollection.getString(attribute));
        }
        dataList.add(map);
    }

    return dataList;
}
```

---

**Edit:**
Sorry, placed important parts of code and used collection directly instead of inserting values in map and process later.

Starting Point:

---

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ImmsClinicalReportApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(ImmsClinicalReportApplication.class, args);
        init(applicationContext);
    }

    private static void init(@NotNull ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ClinicalReportController clinicalReportController = (ClinicalReportController) applicationContext.getBean("clinicalReportController");

        IDfSession dfSession = null;

        try {
            dfSession = clinicalReportController.getSession();
            clinicalReportController.execute(dfSession);
            sendEmail(applicationContext, clinicalReportController);
        } catch (DfException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                clinicalReportController.cleanSession(dfSession);
            } catch (DfException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
@Controller("clinicalReportController")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ClinicalReportController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClinicalReportController.class);

    private final SessionHelper sessionHelper;
    private final DqlHelper dqlHelper;
    private final AppProperties appProperties;

    @Value("${report_path}")
    private String XLSX_FILE_PATH;

    private static final String[] moduleTypes = {
        "Clin Protocol", "Clin Investigator Brochure", "Clin Core Text",
        "Clin Process Documentation", "Clin Supporting Information"
    };

    @Autowired
    public ClinicalReportController(DqlHelper dqlHelper, SessionHelper sessionHelper, AppProperties appProperties) {
        this.dqlHelper = dqlHelper;
        this.sessionHelper = sessionHelper;
        this.appProperties = appProperties;
    }

    /**
     * Method that processes the report
     * @param dfSession dfSession
     * @throws DfException DfException
     * @throws IOException IOException
     */
    public void execute(IDfSession dfSession) throws DfException, IOException {

        StopWatch timer = new StopWatch();

        for (int i = 0; i < moduleTypes.length; i++) {
            // start timer
            timer.start();
            IDfCollection dfCollection = dqlHelper.query(dfSession, QueryConstant.immsQueries[i]);

            List<String> attributes = new ArrayList<>(dfCollection.getAttrCount());

            for (int j = 0; j < dfCollection.getAttrCount(); j++) {
                attributes.add(dfCollection.getAttr(j).getName());
            }

            // stop timer
            timer.stop();
            // Each query takes 20 mins of time
            /* Sample query: select d.r_object_id, d.object_name, d.title,
            d.imms_extreleased_date, d.imms_extreleased_reason, d.imms_extreleaser,
            d.imms_protocol_number, d.imms_protocol_number_rep, d.keywords,
            d.imms_compound_number, d.imms_module_type, d.imms_prereleaser,
            d.imms_prereleased_date, f.r_folder_path from imms_document d,
            dm_folder f where d.i_folder_id=f.r_object_id and i_cabinet_id='0c0033ec80000700'
            and d.imms_module_type = 'Clin Protocol' and d.imms_extreleased_date >
            date('31/12/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') and f.r_folder_path is not nullstring enable (ROW_BASED)*/
            logger.info("Time taken to run query: " + QueryConstant.immsQueries[i] + ": " +
                    timer.getTotalTimeSeconds()/60 + " minutes");

            // List<Map<String, Object>> resultSet = ImmsUtils.insertAttrValues(dfCollection, attributes);

            if (i == 0) {
                processReport(dfCollection, moduleTypes[i], attributes);
            } else {
                updateReport(dfCollection, moduleTypes[i], attributes);
            }
            cleanCollection(dfCollection);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method process for remaining queries/sheets
     * @param resultSet resultSet
     * @param objectType objectType
     * @param attributes attributes
     * @throws IOException IOException
     */
    private void updateReport(IDfCollection resultSet, String objectType, List<String> attributes) throws IOException, DfException {
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(XLSX_FILE_PATH));
        excelWriterAndOperateOutputStream(resultSet, objectType, workbook, attributes);
    }

    /**
     * Method that writes data to excel sheets
     * @param dfCollection dfCollection
     * @param sheet2 sheet2
     * @param workbook workbook
     * @param attributes 
 
     * Using collection directly. Not sure where is the issue in following method, writing data to sheet is also taking 50 minutes of time
     */
     private void writeToSheet(@NotNull IDfCollection dfCollection, Sheet sheet2, Workbook workbook, List<String> attributes) throws DfException {
        Sheet sheet;
        Row row;

        sheet = sheet2;

        Object[] values = new Object[attributes.size()];
        StopWatch timer = new StopWatch();
        
        // moved outside of loop 
        // TODO: avoid regex, use other logic 
        String dateRegex = "^([0-9]{4})/([0-1][0-9])/([0-3][0-9])\\s([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$";
        Pattern datePattern = Pattern.compile(dateRegex);
        // avoid SDF and Date and
        // TODO: use java.time - maybe LocalDate
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = null;

        CellStyle dateCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        dateCellStyle.setDataFormat(workbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));

        timer.start();
        while (dfCollection.next()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < attributes.size(); i++) {
                values[i] = dfCollection.getString(attributes.get(i));
            }

            int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            row = sheet.createRow(++lastRow);
            int cellNum = 0;


            for (Object value: values) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
                if (datePattern.matcher(value.toString()).matches()) {
                    try {
                        date = simpleDateFormat.parse(value.toString());
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    cell.setCellValue(date);
                    cell.setCellStyle(dateCellStyle);
                } else {
                    cell.setCellValue(value.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        timer.stop();
        // Taking 50 mins of time to write collection data
        // Log: Time taken for writing data 54.567404175 minutes
        logger.info("Time taken for writing data " + timer.getTotalTimeSeconds()/60 + " minutes");


        // Resize all columns to fit the content size
        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.size(); i++) {
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to create sheet, set fonts and colors
     * @param moduleType moduleType
     * @param workbook workbook
     * @return Sheet
     */
     private Sheet createSheet(String moduleType, Workbook workbook) {
        return workbook.createSheet(moduleType);
     }

    /**
     * Method to process first query/sheet
     * @param dfCollection dfCollection
     * @param moduleType moduleType
     * @param attributes attributes
     * @throws IOException IOException
     */
     private void processReport(IDfCollection dfCollection, String moduleType, List<String> attributes) throws IOException, DfException {
        // Create a Workbook - for xlsx
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

        /*CreationHelper helps us create instances of various things like DataFormat,
          Hyperlink, RichTextString etc, in a format (HSSF, XSSF) independent way*/
        
        workbook.getCreationHelper();

        excelWriterAndOperateOutputStream(dfCollection, moduleType, workbook, attributes);
    }

    /**
     * Method that writes and saves data to file
     * @param resultSet resultSet
     * @param moduleType  moduleType
     * @param workbook workbook
     * @param attributes attributes
     * @throws IOException IOException
     */
    private void excelWriterAndOperateOutputStream(IDfCollection resultSet, String moduleType, Workbook workbook, List<String> attributes) throws IOException, DfException {
        Sheet sheet = createSheet(moduleType, workbook);

        CellStyle cellStyle = setFontsAndColors(workbook);

        // Create a Row
        Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
        // Create cells
        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.size(); i++) {
            Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
            cell.setCellValue(attributes.get(i));
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
        }

        writeToSheet(resultSet, workbook.getSheet(moduleType), workbook, attributes);
        // Write the output to the file
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(XLSX_FILE_PATH);
        workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
        // close the file
        fileOutputStream.close();
        // close the workbook
        workbook.close();
    }

    @NotNull
    private CellStyle setFontsAndColors(Workbook workbook) {
        CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();

        // Create a Font for styling header cells
        Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
        headerFont.setBold(false);
        headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 12);
        headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
        cellStyle.setFont(headerFont);
        return cellStyle;
   }

    /**
     * Get IDfSession object
     * @return IDfSession
     * @throws DfException DfException
     */
    public IDfSession getSession() throws DfException {
        IDfSession dfSession;

        IDfSessionManager sessionManager = sessionHelper.getDfSessionManager(appProperties.getRepository(), appProperties.getUsername(), appProperties.getPassword());
        dfSession = sessionManager.getSession(appProperties.getRepository());
        return dfSession;
    }

    /**
     * Clean IDfCollection
     * @param dfCollection dfCollection
     */
    public void cleanCollection(IDfCollection dfCollection) {
        dqlHelper.cleanup(dfCollection);
    }

    /**
     * Clean IDfSession
     * @param dfSession dfSession
     */
    public void cleanSession(IDfSession dfSession) throws DfException {
        sessionHelper.cleanSession(dfSession);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Any particular reason for using `LinkedHashMap` over `HashMap`?

Comment: For start you could replace ArrayList with LinkedList, ArrayList need to rewrite all elements to a bigger array, when it gets full. Second issue: use HashMap instead of LinkedHashMap

Comment: Using LinkedHashMap to maintain insertion order, I tried using HashMap it is inserting data incorrectly for my requirement. Will try using LinkedList.

Comment: Try to simply iterate over dfCollection results (without saving them), and see if the time is also high. This might suggest that the cursor is not fetching enough records in one swoop and must do multiple IO operations, which are very slow. Try then increasing fetch size for each query. As for LinkedHashMap you can. use HashMap, because the order of attributes is the same in attributes collection, so this way you can get the values in correct order. LinkedHashMap can be up to 30% slower when inserting, but that depends on the scale.

Comment: Why are you converting `IDfCollection` into `List<Map<String, Object>>` at first and not filling the appropriate POI structures directly?

Are you sure that only the `insertAttrValues` method is slow? What about the DQL query execution time?

Comment: I used Timer, it took 1 hour and I saw in the logs for each query insertion as I have added the code above. Will try saving data directly as you suggested.

Comment: By the way, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), `GregorianCalendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: In your last block of code, what is the difference between the regex and the `SimpleDateFormat`? Don't they accomplish the same thing? Why the `if - else`? And, what are the possible types of `Object` argument? I assume your 3,000-3,500 rows are three thousand `Map` elements contained in your `List`, but… Where are you writing the 14 columns in this code? If your code were a bit more clear, I would take a stab at recreating the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is with query. Try below steps:

- Instead of giving individual attributes in `select` query, use `*`. See the query execution time. If the execution is fast without taking minutes of time, try the next steps.

`select * from imms_document d, dm_folder f where d.i_folder_id=f.r_object_id and i_cabinet_id='0c0033ec80000700' and d.imms_module_type = 'Clin Protocol' and d.imms_extreleased_date > date('31/12/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') and f.r_folder_path is not nullstring enable (ROW_BASED)`

- As you are using Spring Boot, include required attributes in `application.properties` as shown below. You may not want all.

`included_attributes=r_object_id,object_name,title,imms_extreleased_date,imms_extreleased_reason,imms_extreleaser,imms_protocol_number,imms_protocol_number_rep,keywords,imms_compound_number,imms_module_type,imms_prereleaser,imms_prereleased_date,r_folder_path`

Do the following in your `AppProperties` class file:

```
@Component
public class AppProperties {

   /**
    *other fields
    */

    @Getter
    @Value("${included_attributes}")
    private String[] includedAttributes;

}
```

Now in your `execute()` method, modify the code to use only the attributes you need to get the data for.

```
public void execute(IDfSession dfSession) throws DfException, IOException {

    StopWatch timer = new StopWatch();

    for (int i = 0; i < moduleTypes.length; i++) {
        // start timer
        timer.start();
        IDfCollection dfCollection = dqlHelper.query(dfSession, QueryConstant.immsQueries[i]);
        // stop timer
        timer.stop();
        logger.info("Time taken to run query: " + QueryConstant.immsQueries[i] + ": " +
                timer.getTotalTimeSeconds() + " seconds");    
        // attributes to be added
        List<String> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
        // Get included attributes as list
        List<String> includedAttributes = Arrays.asList(appProperties.getIncludedAttributes());

        for (int j = 0; j < dfCollection.getAttrCount(); j++) {
            // check for the attribute in included attributes and add if exists
            if (hasAttribute(includedAttributes, dfCollection.getAttr(j).getName())) {
                attributes.add(dfCollection.getAttr(j).getName());
            }
        }


        if (i == 0) {
            processReport(dfCollection, moduleTypes[i], attributes);
        } else {
            updateReport(dfCollection, moduleTypes[i], attributes);
        }
        cleanCollection(dfCollection);
    }
}

public static boolean hasAttribute(@NotNull List<String> attributes, String attribute) {
    for(String attr : attributes){
        if(attribute.contains(attr)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Directly use collection for POI structures and no need to insert data in array and iterate over it again.

```
private void writeToSheet(@NotNull IDfCollection dfCollection, Sheet sheet2,
                              @NotNull Workbook workbook, List<String> attributes) throws DfException {
        Sheet sheet;
        Row row;

        sheet = sheet2;

        StopWatch timer = new StopWatch();

        String dateRegex = "^([0-9]{4})/([0-1][0-9])/([0-3][0-9])\\s([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$";
        Pattern datePattern = Pattern.compile(dateRegex);

        DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

        CellStyle dateCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        dateCellStyle.setDataFormat(workbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));

        int lastRow = 0;

        timer.start();
        while (dfCollection.next()) {
            row = sheet.createRow(++lastRow);
            int cellNum = 0;

            for (String attribute : attributes) {
                Object value = dfCollection.getString(attribute);

                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);

                if (datePattern.matcher(value.toString()).matches()) {
                    cell.setCellValue(LocalDateTime.parse(value.toString(), timeFormatter));
                    cell.setCellStyle(dateCellStyle);
                } else {
                    cell.setCellValue(value.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        timer.stop();
        logger.info("Time taken for writing data " + timer.getTotalTimeSeconds()/60 + " minutes");


        // Resize all columns to fit the content size
        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.size(); i++) {
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow, the query execution is fast it took only 30-50 seconds after using *. Now my whole program runs within 5 mins. Brilliant, time saviour. Wondering how using * resolved the issue as it contains more columns than giving individual attributes. Even IDfCollection is fast in getting data for this query now.

Answer (score 4):

You can do these improvements:

1. Fill in the POI structures directly from `IDfCollection` and do not copy collection data into `List<Map<String, Object>>`.
2. Use `collection.getTime(attribute)` to obtain time value instead of regex parsing of each record. You can use `collection.getAttrDataType(attribute) == IDfAttr.DF_TIME` condition to resolve if the value is time or not.
3. Then you can use date directly without parsing like this: `cell.setCellValue(collection.getTime(attribute).getDate())`
4. But the same is for numbers and then you can have better result in excel sheet. It means to use `collection.getInt(attribute)` and `collection.getDouble(attribute)` instead of `collection.getString(attribute)`. Constants like `IDfAttr.DM_INTEGER` and `IDfAttr.DM_DOUBLE` will also help here.
5. Move `int last_row` outside of the for loop and and do `last_row++` inside of the loop. Calling of `sheet.getLastRowNum()` is not necessary then. BTW: camel case name `lastRow` would be nicer in Java world ;-)

Another thing is that you are calling the whole process in another loop for *5 similar queries*, so there can be probably another space for improvements like conversions of all queries into one using for example better conditions, `UNION` if possible, wider condition + filter in application logic, ...).

Comment: To that to-do list, I would add: Moving the `Pattern datePattern = Pattern.compile(regex);` lines outside the loop.

Comment: Ok, will compile regex takes a bit time? Moved outside of loop as per your suggestion.

Comment: @cgrim Thanks for the steps. How to use your 2nd point my writeToSheet() method? Bit confusing to use while trying. It is giving numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the forkjoinPoll or use jdk's stream parallel:), use your cpu's multiple core processer. For forkjoinpool example please refer https://www.baeldung.com/java-fork-join

```
  public static List<Map<String, Object>> insertAttrValues(Stream<Object> stream, List<String> attributes) throws RuntimeException {
    if (stream == null || attributes == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("collection and attributes");
    }
    final int size = attributes.size();
    return stream.parallel().map(item -> {
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(size);
        for (String attribute : attributes) {
            //map.put(attribute, item.getString(attribute));
        }
        return map;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: This will not help him because he is using Documentum `IDfCollection` as a source and not Java Stream and `IDfCollection` must be read sequentially using `next()` method.

Comment: if we can get the Idfcollection size then we can use the forkjoinPool and split with sub-task running at the same time.